# Vue 3: Change a parent component ref value from an inner child component using the Composition API

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have created a dynamic tab navigation where all the data is asynchronous. Everything is working fine: I'm using inject/provide to pass data across the components, and I can add chats from a queue in real-time to the tab system but the problem is that when I remove a tab from a button on a child component (that means to remove an element from the chats array in the app state) I can't find a way to render the first tab by default on the DOM, so the screen will always show any tab selected and a blank screen:

This is the page view:

```
  <BaseTabsWrapper>
    <BaseTab
      v-for="chatSession in incomingChatSessions"
      :key="chatSession.id"
      :title="chatSession.endUser.name"
    >
      <section class="header">
        <BaseClientHeader :chatSession="chatSession" />
      </section>
      <section class="content">
        <div class="flex mt-4">
          <section class="chat-area w-5/12">
            <BaseChatWidget :chatSession="chatSession" class="mt-4" />
          </section>
          <section class="ticket-area w-7/12 ml-6">
            <p>The Ticket Area</p>
            <p class="mt-4">{{ chatSession.id }}</p>
          </section>
        </div>
      </section>
    </BaseTab>
  </BaseTabsWrapper>
```

This is the BaseTabWrapper component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul
      class="tag-menu flex space-x-2"
      :class="defaultTagMenu ? 'default' : 'historic'"
      role="tablist"
      aria-label="Tabs Menu"
      v-if="tabTitles && tabTitles.length"
    >
      <li
        @click.stop.prevent="selectedTitle = title"
        v-for="title in tabTitles"
        :key="title"
        :title="title"
        role="presentation"
        :class="{ selected: title === selectedTitle }"
      >
        <a href="#" role="tab">
          {{ title }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, useSlots, provide } from "vue";
export default {
  props: {
    defaultTagMenu: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const slots = useSlots();
    const tabTitles = computed(() =>
      slots.default()[0].children.map((tab) => tab.props.title)
    );
    const selectedTitle = ref(tabTitles.value[0]);
    provide("selectedTitle", selectedTitle);
    provide("tabTitles", tabTitles);
    return {
      tabTitles,
      selectedTitle,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see I'm using slots.default in order to create a title array, that way I can pass the title as a prop to the BaseTab component and paint the titles. The problem is that when I remove a tab from a button inside a child component this part keeps having the old navigation value:

```
const selectedTitle = ref(tabTitles.value[0]);
```

**What I want to do is for selectedTitle to have that ref(tabTitles.value[0]) whenever I remove a chat so the selected tab is always the first one.**

This is the BaseTab component:

```
<template>
  <div v-show="title === selectedTitle" class="mt-4">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { inject } from "vue";
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: "Tab Title",
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const selectedTitle = inject("selectedTitle");
    return {
      selectedTitle,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```